# I cannot convert list into float in script despite being able to do so via the interpreter?

Tags: python-2.7

I am having an issue with a script I made tasked with finding certain numbers in a text file and returning those values as floating numbers.

```
import re

fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "ip.txt"
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    numbers = re.findall('^92.[0-9.]+', line)
    if len(numbers) != 1 : continue
    num = [float(i) for i in numbers]
    print num
```

I get a traceback as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File ".\test1.py", line 9, in <module> num = [float(i) for i in numbers]
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 92.43.17.152
```

The ip.txt file is just a text file with one IP address on each line:

```
93.77.231.193
```

Comment: `re.findall('^92.[0-9.]+', '92.43.17.152')` is `['92.43.17.152']`, so your claim that it worked in the interpreter isn't very convincing.

Comment: Well then my claim is wrong but my issue still remains.  I am new to coding. I am not a developer, just a NOC support technician.

Comment: The question is a little ambiguous on what you want the result to be.
when talking about IP addresses it is unlikely that a float is the output that you want. you could split it into a list of int's so that you can use each number how you like?

Comment: That's what I just realized. Of course a floating number can only have one decimal place. I feel dumb! Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have 92.43.17.52 (starts with 92) in your text file, which matches the regular expression you are searching for. Then your code unsuccessfully tries to convert it to floating point, since floating point numbers can have only one . in them. What numbers exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Oops. You are right. Of course it can't be converted to a float straight up! Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 

    numbers = ['192.168.1.1']

    num = [int(i) for i in numbers[0].split('.')]

num = [192,168,1,1]
```

Comment: I think this is the output you are looking for, a list which contains all of the relevant individual values of an IP address.

Comment: Thanks again! I appreciate it.